# Can we know if a specific user is currently logged in using Passport JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

We can know if the person trying to access routes, etc, is or is not a user. Can we know if a specific user is online, or if a specific user is visiting a specific page?

```
req.user
```

Is not sufficient here.

Comment: You will need to use redis to make this work.

Comment: @Darkrum can you suggest any tutorial or link please

Answer (score 0):

Passport is providing the mechanism to authenticate the user. The situation that you want to implement needs the different modules. Like whether user is online or not can be done using the socket.io module. and user is visiting specific page can be track by server side caching and redis is the one of the way as said by @[Darkrum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4474451/darkrum).